# Running DNU Restore on VSO build

Tags: asp.net-core, tfsbuild, azure-devops, dnx, .net-4.6

I am trying to get DNX projects building on VSO's host agent.

First thing is installing DNX.  I have the following powershell script to do this:

**dnx-upgrade.ps1:**

```
dnvm upgrade -r clr -arch x86 -v 1.0.0-beta6
```

It successfully installs and PATH is updated:

> Adding
>   C:\Users\buildguest.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6\bin to
>   process PATH
>   Adding
>   C:\Users\buildguest.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6\bin to
>   user PATH

Then I need to restore the solution's packages with this script:

**dnu-restore.ps1:**

```
dnu restore
```

But I get the following error when executing dnu-restore.ps1:

> [error]dnu : The term 'dnu' is not
>   recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
>   program. Check the
>   [error]spelling
>   of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
>   correct and try again.
>   [error]At
>   C:\a\8ac4a4f6\Root\MyProject\Development\dnu-restore.ps1:1 char:1
>   [error]+ dnu restore
>   [error]+ ~~~
>   [error]    + CategoryInfo          :
>   ObjectNotFound: (dnu:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   [error]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId :
>   CommandNotFoundException

**Build tasks:**

[image: Build tasks]

Why is this happening? Surely `dnu` should execute? Is there a better way to restore DNX project packages?

Comment: Can you add all the build steps in a single script? I'm not sure how VSO starts each build step but it can happen that the parent process started before the environment variable is set by dnvm and the subsequent build steps don't pick up the changes.

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci: yeah, something weird is going on...like the post says `Adding C:\Users\buildguest.dnx\runtimes\dnx-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta6\bin to user PATH` which means it should have been available to the second script...@davenewza: do you still see this issue?

Comment: @KiranChalla Not necessarily. I know that some build servers, like TeamCity, run each step in a different process. So, if one process adds something to the path, the second one will not pick it up because they have the same parent process which was started before the env var was set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `Prebuild.ps1` script from [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/vs/alm/Build/azure/deploy-aspnet5) solved the problem.

As Victor suggested, it may be because the steps are run in different processes.